# How do I download Xcode Documentation

Tags: xcode

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro to 10.13, and installed Xcode 9

Xcode is working, but I don't seem to have the latest Libraries.
Previously this was a manual process which took some time. Searching I found 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

This states "You obtain Xcode 9 from the Mac App Store. It is a free download that installs directly into the Applications folder. By default, Xcode downloads developer documentation in the background for offline reading; it also automatically downloads documentation updates. This behavior can be changed after installation using the Downloads preferences pane."

As far as I can see this is not happening, and I can't find any "Downloads preferences pane"

Comment: What libraries are you referring to?